# When to use init() when creating UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, initialization, viewdidload

In the past I always used `viewDidLoad` to initialise my `ViewControllers`, mostly to perform additional initialization on views as it is suggested by `Apple's` documentation. Sometimes however, I also `initialise` model objects in the `viewDidLoad` that help me to do a certain task. Here is an example code:

```
override fun viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialisation of my views
    self.label.text = "text"
    self.imageView.image = UIImage( named: "image" )
    etc.
    .
    .

    // Initialisation of my models
    self.videoRecorder = VideoRecorder()
    etc.
    .
    .
}
```

When I think about it now, doesn't it make more sense to put model initialisation the `init` method of the `ViewController`?

I apologise in advance if my question seems obvious, however I found that in most `iOS` tutorials I have seen, people tend to only perform `initialisation` in the `viewDidLoad` method.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason people usually do not do this is because view controllers often get instantiated from storyboards and xib files. When that is the case, **the normal `init` is not called**. Instead `initiWithCoder:` is used and then any properties marked with `IBOutlet` are set accordingly.

Note that this **very** often makes initializing properties redundant, as they tend to be set via `IBOutlet` as well.

So if you want your view controller to properly work also when just using it with init, ensure you won't have troubles when it's used from a storyboard (unless you're absolutely certain that will never happen), you would most likely have to implement both, `init` and `initWithCoder:`. I have seen a lot of people running into problems because they expected a property set in `init` to be there in `viewDidLoad` (when loading the controller from a storyboard).

Because of all this, most programmers don't bother about `init` and rely on `viewDidLoad`, because that is definitely called at some point. Writing a proper "both ways usable" controller is just more code.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not advised to perform tasks in a constructor (`init()`). However creating an object which is a property of a `ViewController` can be considered a simple initialization, so it looks OK to do it in the `init()`.

Each case should be considered separately depending on the nature of the model you create and its responsibilities.

The thumb rule is: *performing tasks - no, initializing properties - yes*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're initializing viewController variables using data passed in from a segue, then it works better (from my personal experience) to do it in viewDidLoad instead of init. When I tried to initialize from init, the viewController did not get the values passed in from the segue.